# Azure Logic Apps - Convert JSON Epoch Timestamp to DateTime String

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

I am working on an Azure Logic App that is triggered via an HTTP call and returns a JSON response.  Internally, the logic app retrieves JSON data from a web API and then converts the response JSON data to a format that is acceptable to the calling client of the logic app.

The problem I'm having is that the web API is returning dates in the format `"/Date(1616371200000)/"` and I need the date format to look like `"2021-03-32T19:00:00Z"`.  I don't see any [built-in logic app function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#date-and-time-functions) that can work with or convert the Epoch timestamp as-is (unless I'm missing something).

To clarify...

Source Data:

```
{
    "some_silly_date": "/Date(1616371200000)/"
}
```

Desired Data:

```
{
    "some_silly_date": "2021-03-32T19:00:00Z"
}
```

The following solution would theoretically work if the source date wasn't wrapped with `"/Date(...)/"`:

```
"@addToTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z', 1616371200000, 'Second')"
```

Parsing that text off the timestamp before converting it would lead to a really ugly expression.  Is there a better way to convert the timestamp that I'm not aware of?

*Note that using the [Liquid JSON-to-JSON templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform) is not an option.  I was using that and found this action apparently has to JIT compile before use which is causing my logic app to time-out when being called after a long period of inactivity.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following expression seems to be working and returns a timestamp in UTC.  Note that the `substring()` function is only using a length of 10 instead of 13.  I'm intentionally trimming-off the milliseconds from the Epoch timestamp because the `addToTime()` function only handles seconds.

```
{
   "some_silly_date": "@addToTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z', int(substring(item()?['some_silly_date'],6,10)), 'Second')"
}
```

As an added bonus, if the timestamp value is `null` in the source JSON, do the following:

```
{
   "some_silly_date": "@if(equals(item()?['some_silly_date'], null), null, addToTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z', int(substring(item()?['some_silly_date'],6,10)), 'Second'))"
}
```

Quite possibly the ugliest code I've ever written.

Comment: The length of substring can't be longer than '10' which is the length of the source string.https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#substring :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you get the value "/Date(1616371200000)/" from the JSON into a variable? If so, a little string manipulation would do the trick:

[image]

```
int(replace(replace(variables('data_in'),'/Date(',''),')/',''))
```

Then use the variable in the *addToTime* function.

Result:

[image]

Comment: My example JSON was greatly simplified as the real JSON I'm mapping from has multiple timestamp fields, thus assigning variables for each timestamp would be less than ideal.

Comment: The variable is optional and just helps with clarity. You can just use the code example inline without a variable. If the problem you are trying to solve is different than what was presented, you may want to edit your question to get more appropriate answers.