# Convert Epoch Unix Date to hh:ss Am/Pm format

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

How to convert format epoch timestamp string to 'hh:mm Am/Pm' format in logic apps

Comment: What is your programming language ? How is this related to Azure functions ?

Comment: @MoNazemi I am using azure logic apps not any specific programming language and i reckon solution should be achieved using workflow expression functions

Comment: @RajatBajaj I removed the tag for functions. You’ve confused the tag with what Azure functions are. Also, have you searched for your answer because it very much exists.  https://consultwithgriff.com/azure-logic-apps-epoch-time/

Answer (score 0):

**Reference1:**
I agree with @Skin . Also, have you searched for your [answer](https://consultwithgriff.com/azure-logic-apps-epoch-time/) because it very much exists.

You can follow any of these below mentioned references also.

**Reference 2**:
**Convert JSON Epoch Timestamp to DateTime String- Azure [Logicapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67234245/azure-logic-apps-convert-json-epoch-timestamp-to-datetime-string) **

As mentioned in above reference thread try this one

```perl
{
   "some_silly_date": "@addToTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z', int(substring(item()?['some_silly_date'],6,10)), 'Second')"
}
```

or if you want it from the **JSON into a variable** try with **initialize variable action** in logic App as shown below.
[image]
[image]

```lisp
int(replace(replace(variables('data_in'),'/Date(',''),')/',''))
```

**Reference 3.** You can follow @[Justion Yoo](https://devkimchi.com/2018/11/04/converting-tick-or-epoch-to-timestamp-in-logic-app/) document also.

**Reference 4**. Initially you are using azure functions tag also in your question so if you want to Convert Unix timestamp to DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS format in other coding domain like C++ , C # follow this [document](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-unix-timestamp-to-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-format/)

5. https://www.epochconverter.com/?q=1600000000